# Length of substring if we just consider a subdivision in $\log n$ substrings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, formal-languages

Let $u$ be a string of length $n$ and consider a subdivision in $\log n$ substrings $u = u_1 u_2 \cdots u_{\log n}$. Is it true that there exists a constant $C$ such that for each $1 \le i \le \log n$ the string
$$
 u_1 u_2 \cdots u_{i-1} u_{i+1} \cdots u_{\log n}
$$
has length smaller then $\frac{\log n - 1}{\log n}\cdot n + C$, i.e.
$$
 \left| u_1 u_2 \cdots u_{i-1} u_{i+1} \cdots u_{\log n} \right| \le \frac{\log n - 1}{\log n}\cdot n  + O(1)?
$$

Comment: This seems false, for example if even one $u_i$ has length one.

Comment: I do not see that... set $q_n := (\log n - 1)/\log n$, so $q_n \to 1$, then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $n \approx q_n n$, so that $n < q_n n + 1$ would hold for sufficiently large $n$, which gives $n - 1 < q_n n$. Now let $N$ be the smallest such $n$, then the constant $C$ could be picked by considering the finite cases $1-1 < q_1 \cdot 1, 2-1 < q_2 \cdot 2, \ldots, N-1 < q_N \cdot N$ so that the inequality holds, i.e. set $C = \max\{ | i - 1 - q_i i| + 1 : i = 1,\ldots, N \}$?

Comment: No! Write $q_n =(1 - 1/\log n)$.  You're claiming that, for large $n$, $n < q_n+1$, i.e. $n < n(1-1/\log n) + 1$, i.e. $n/\log n<1$.  You have to be very careful about vague statements such as $n\approx q_n n$; it's true that the *ratio* of $n$ to $q_n n$ tends to one, but the *difference* is unbounded.

Comment: Yes, I somehow thought that $\lim_n (n - q_n n) = \lim_n n(1-q_n) = 0$, but of course trying to use limit theorems we have $\infty \cdot 0$, which is not defined. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note it is impossible to have all your substrings have length greater than $n / \log n$ So let's make a very mild assumption, let's assume that for increasing $n$ we have our strings $u_i$ such that the length of $u_1$ is $o(n / \log n)$. This means $\lim_{n \to \infty} |u_1| / (n / \log n) = 0$. Note your condition is equivalent to the length, when we remove $u_1$, being $\leq n - n/\log n + C$. And the length when you remove $u_1$ is $n - |u_1|$. Subtracting $n$ gives $|u_1| \geq n / \log n - C$, as $n$ increases. But this contradicts $|u_1| = o(n / \log n)$.